# Hibernate5 ignores Lazy load

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, spring-boot

I am trying to use hibernate5:

my configurate class:

```
@Configuration
@EnableTransactionManagement
public class HibernateConfiguration {

    @Value("${db.driver}")
    private String DB_DRIVER;

    @Value("${db.password}")
    private String DB_PASSWORD;

    @Value("${db.url}")
    private String DB_URL;

    @Value("${db.username}")
    private String DB_USERNAME;

    @Value("${hibernate.dialect}")
    private String HIBERNATE_DIALECT;

    @Value("${hibernate.show_sql}")
    private String HIBERNATE_SHOW_SQL;

    @Value("${entitymanager.packagesToScan}")
    private String ENTITYMANAGER_PACKAGES_TO_SCAN;

    @Value("${hibernate.enable_lazy_load_no_trans}")
    private String ENABLE_LAZY_LOAD;

    @Bean
    public LocalSessionFactoryBean sessionFactory() {
        LocalSessionFactoryBean sessionFactory = new LocalSessionFactoryBean();
        sessionFactory.setDataSource(dataSource());
        sessionFactory.setPackagesToScan(ENTITYMANAGER_PACKAGES_TO_SCAN);
        sessionFactory.setHibernateProperties(hibernateProperties());
        return sessionFactory;
    }

    @Bean
    public PlatformTransactionManager hibernateTransactionManager() {
        HibernateTransactionManager transactionManager
                = new HibernateTransactionManager();
        transactionManager.setSessionFactory(sessionFactory().getObject());
        return transactionManager;
    }


    @Bean
    public DataSource dataSource() {
        DriverManagerDataSource dataSource = new DriverManagerDataSource();
        dataSource.setDriverClassName(DB_DRIVER);
        dataSource.setUrl(DB_URL);
        dataSource.setUsername(DB_USERNAME);
        dataSource.setPassword(DB_PASSWORD);
        return dataSource;
    }

    private final Properties hibernateProperties() {
        Properties hibernateProperties = new Properties();
        hibernateProperties.put("hibernate.dialect", HIBERNATE_DIALECT);
        hibernateProperties.put("hibernate.show_sql", HIBERNATE_SHOW_SQL);
        hibernateProperties.put("hibernate.enable_lazy_load_no_trans", ENABLE_LAZY_LOAD);

        return hibernateProperties;
    }

}
```

and my DAO:

```
@Service("userDAO_mysql")
@Transactional
public class UserDAOImpl implements UserDAO {
    @Override
    public User getAllUsers(){
        Session session = sessionFactory.getCurrentSession();
        return session.getSession().get(User.class,0);
    }
}
```

My user has FetchType set to LazyLoad to any `@OneToMany` relation. However, all relations are loaded just by using:

```
User u = userDAO.getAllUsers();
```

I have failed to make it otherwise. 
Are there any tricks for this to work as it should? Or i am missing something?

Thanks for help!

// edit , just for claryfication, i have been using this up to this date, and decided to use more relevant way:

```
public class HibernateUtil {
    private static StandardServiceRegistry registry;
    private static SessionFactory sessionFactory;

    public static SessionFactory getSessionFactory() {
        if (sessionFactory == null) {
            try {
                // Create registry
                registry = new StandardServiceRegistryBuilder()
                        .configure()
                        .build();

                // Create MetadataSources
                MetadataSources sources = new MetadataSources(registry);

                // Create Metadata
                Metadata metadata = sources.getMetadataBuilder().build();

                // Create SessionFactory
                sessionFactory = metadata.getSessionFactoryBuilder().build();

            } catch (Exception e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
                if (registry != null) {
                    StandardServiceRegistryBuilder.destroy(registry);
                }
            }
        }
        return sessionFactory;
    }

    public static void shutdown() {
        if (registry != null) {
            StandardServiceRegistryBuilder.destroy(registry);
        }
    }
}

public User getUserById(int id) {
    User u = null;
    Session session = HibernateUtil.getSessionFactory().openSession();
    Transaction tx = null;
    Integer employeeID = null;

    try {
        tx = session.beginTransaction();
        Criteria cr = session.createCriteria(User.class).add(Restrictions.eq("id",id));
        u = (User) cr.uniqueResult();
    } catch (HibernateException e) {
        if (tx!=null) tx.rollback();
        e.printStackTrace();
    } finally {
        session.close();
    }
    return u;
}
```

This way lazy loading was not ignored, the lazy load:

```
    @OneToMany(mappedBy="user",cascade=CascadeType.ALL,fetch=FetchType.LAZY,
orphanRemoval=true)
    public Set<Topic> getTopics() {
        return topics;
    }

public void setTopics(Set<Topic> topics) {
    this.topics = topics;
}
```

Comment: Please share the user class.

Comment: Where is the `User` class? And since `UserDAO` manages `User` it's normal that `userDAO.getAllUsers()` returns all users.

Comment: The User class should be fine, i was using HibernateUtil factory for session and the lazy loading worked as expected, i have updated question.

Answer (score -1):

lets assume that parent is the first entity which has @onetomany relation to children and the lazyload is set true on @onetomany

you can still call the parent.getChildren() method in the service class,it will fetch them,but if you try this in your controller class,you will get the lazy load exception.

this scenario is useful when u only need the parent,so u just retrieve the parent object.
if you need the children,u call the method you just mentioned and it will retrieve all children of that parent for you(in your controller class)

Comment: the point is, the lazy load exception does not occur, and the @onetomany realtions are loaded right away.